# Pine Script / Trading View - Calculating Trading Day of Month (TDOM)

Tags: pine-script

I want to calculate the Trading Day of the Month in (TDOM) in TradingView/Pine Script.

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
int counter = 0

if (month != month[1])
    counter := 0

if (dayofmonth != dayofmonth[1])
    counter := counter + 1

plot(counter)
```

Any thoughts/help on how I can get TDOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `var` keyword, or else your `counter` will be reset to 0 at every bar.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

var int counter = 0

if ta.change(month)
    counter := 0

if ta.change(dayofmonth)
    counter += 1

plot(counter)
```