# Pick closing value of last Thursday of month

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I need to pick closing value of last Thursday of month and then apply standard deviation to it.  How can I do so?  If Thursday is trading holiday then it should be Wednesday but not Friday.

I saw one code here - [Pine Script / Trading View - Calculating Trading Day of Month (TDOM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70501762/pine-script-trading-view-calculating-trading-day-of-month-tdom)  but I do not know how to change it to what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pine script currently doesn't have a trading days calendar, so it's impossible (AFAIK) to check if it's the last trading day.

We can check if we are on the [last week of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74640158/get-the-last-trading-day-of-the-month-in-pine-script) and in addition check if it's Thursday. It won't work on all cases (for example in case where on the last week there is no trading day on a Thursday) but it will work in most cases.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay = true)

f_is_leap_year() =>
    if ((year % 4) != 0)
        false
    else if ((year % 100) != 0)
        true
    else if ((year % 400) == 0)
        true
    else
        false

f_get_last_day() =>
    if (month == 1) or (month == 3) or (month == 5) or (month == 7) or (month == 8) or (month == 10) or (month == 12)
        31
    else if (month == 4) or (month == 6) or (month == 9) or (month == 11)
        30
    else
        f_is_leap_year() ? 29 : 28  // February

last_thursday = dayofmonth > f_get_last_day() - 7 and dayofweek == dayofweek.thursday

plotshape(last_thursday)
```